# Monodevelop on (G)Ubuntu: Bad scaling on HiDPI Display

Tags: 15.04, display, display-resolution, monodevelop

I am trying out to use MonoDevelop on a Dell XPS 13 (13 inch screen with 3200x1800 resolution).

I have set the window scaling property in the gnome tweak tool to "2" and most applications behave nicely.

Monodevelop however scales horribly (see picture): The build / status box in the top center and the start page have a way too small font. Also, most dialogs are opened way too small (settings), as are some views (property view).

Is there any way / option to fix this?
I'm using GUbuntu 15.04

[image: screenshot of monodevelop on a HiDPI display, ubuntu]

Comment: Well the question was written Oktober 2015 which wasn't EOL at this time. However, this problem is still available in Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Still the same for Ubuntu 16.10 (MonoDevelop version 5.10)

Answer (score 0):

Try to scale using 'Scalling' option - 100%/200% or fractal scaling instead of per application Gnome tweaks. When the app is broken there is not a lot you can do without rewriting its' code. I own my second XPS13(9310, previously 9343) and I find putting 4K screen to 13'' form factor a miscarriage. Sometimes nothing is as helpful as temporary 'downgrading' resolution to FullHD, you can even script arround `xrandr` and attach keyboard shortcuts to it. Also you can use same gnome tweaks to scale properly coded apps the other way when your current resolution is low DPI as a workaround to MonoDevelop.
Also make sure your aspect ratio is the same as original ? As some XPS's 13' are using 16:10 and some do use 16:9 ratio.

Comment: Needs some references.

Comment: what exactly do you need ?